# Publish Float64MultiArray from command line - ROS2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't seem to figure this out:

`ros2 topic pub /gripper_controller/commands std_msgs/msg/Float64MultiArray lay`  [TAB COMPLETE]

Now the message is auto-populated like this. I just change the data field:

```
ros2 topic pub /gripper_controller/commands std_msgs/msg/Float64MultiArray layout:\
\ \ dim:\ []\
\ \ data_offset:\ 0\
data:\ [0.2]\
```

^ When I try that, the error is:

> yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping
> values are not allowed here   in
> "", line 1, column 13:
> layout:  dim: []  data_offset: 0data: [0.2]

Similar issues if I use the rqt message publisher.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383725/publish-float64multiarray-from-command-line---ros2/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2021-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah, found an example in ros2_control_demos:

```
ros2 topic pub /gripper_controller/commands std_msgs/msg/Float64MultiArray "data:
- 0.1"
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2021-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0